# MySQL Data Import from .csv stops at 9000 records?

Tags: mysql, excel, database, csv, mysql-workbench

I have a weird problem.
My MySQL table import wizard stops the import of a .csv file at 9000 records (45000 records total).
I already opened the .csv with notepad++ to see if any hidden characters are in the file so that the import cancels, but nothing.
[Stops the import at the marked line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fACp.png)
[Here is a picture of the table import wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9GCE.png)

Do you have any idea if there any limiations to the import of a .csv? 
Or what else could cause this to happen?

Comment: What is your `max_allowed_packet` option configured to? How does this compare to the amount of data you imported? It could be truncating the data.

Comment: What is in your .csv at line 9000?  Anything strange?  What is the last row actually imported? Is anything strange in your .csv at that line or the line after? Strange=wrong number of columns, bad character, etc. I've successfully used workbench to import many more rows that 9000.

Answer (score -1):

What the encoding of file? (utf8/cp866 etc) And check the file line break symbol.
If I were you, I would try to import from the console.

Like this:

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  
'c:/temp/some-file.csv'
INTO TABLE your_awesome_table  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(field_1,field_2 , field_3);
```

Comment: It's uft8. Notepad++ says it's encoded with uft8 and the table import wizard is also configured with uft8, so I think this should be ok.

Comment: So, after finally getting this query to work, it also only imports 9000 rows. I will have to take another look at the data.

Comment: line breaks checked?

Comment: @markus  You still have not told us the size of the CSV file in KB.  Please post results of SELECT @@max_allowed_packet; .  This is the SIZE limit of the INPUT file.  Option is to make multiple input files to be posted one at a time.

Comment: Hey guys, thx for the help! Now it suddenly worked with this query... I copied the data in a new excel file and with this new file it suddenly worked. So I guess there was something going on with the .csv...

Answer (score -1):

Probable problems:

1. Maybe the problem is the need for RAM space, because the first 8999 lines work well, right? But there is a time when the programs stop.
2. Maybe the csv file on line 9000 has an incorrect character or value and the program could not interpret it.
3. Maybe the csv file is corrupted.

Comment: How can i determine if the RAM is the problem? I have about 8GB and when importing the data about 4GB of it gets used.

Comment: Open Task Manager and check how much RAM the program is using while importing the data.

Comment: I saw your photo and I think that the program could have a limitation or maybe the csv file got 44100 null records